# How to load a full calendar with a particular year chosen from a text box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I am having a full calendar that is loading and working properly, but I need to choose one particular year only, in the full calendar, by selecting a year from one of my text boxes.

How to do that in javascript?

My code and designs are below:

**Text box to choose year:**

```
    <div class="col-lg-3">
<label>Calendar Year</label>
<div class="input-group date">
<input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="CalendarYear">
<div class="input-group-addon bg-purple">
<i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Script to choose year only:**

```
<script>      
        $(function () {
            $("#CalendarYear").datepicker({
                autoclose: true,
                format: "yyyy",
                viewMode: "years",
                minViewMode: "years"
            });
          });
    </script>
```

**Design for full calendar:**

```
<div class="box box-primary">
<div class="box-body no-padding">
<!-- THE CALENDAR -->
<div id="calendar_full"></div>
</div>
<!-- /.box-body -->
</div>
```

**Javascript to load full calendar:**

```
  <script>
        $(function () {        

            /* initialize the calendar
             -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
            //Date for the calendar events (dummy data)
            var date = new Date()
            var d = date.getDate(),
                m = date.getMonth(),
                y = date.getFullYear()
            $('#calendar_full').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month' //agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                buttonText: {
                    today: 'today',
                    month: 'month',
                    //week: 'week',
                    //day: 'day'
                }                 
            })  
})   
    </script>
```

**Full calendar image as follows:** [image]

**My text box to choose year: Design as follows**

[image]

**Everything works fine. What I need is, when I choose a year from the calendar year text box, let's say 2017, my full calendar must only load Jan 2017 to Dec 2017. Likewise, the calendar needs to display the year chosen, by using javascript**. How to do it? Kindly help. TIA.

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/gotoDate

Comment: @ADyson but this page doesn't explain the exact detail that I need... Is there any other way or link available that related to my query?Kindly help

Comment: what part of the process is still puzzling you? That links shows you the method you need to call in order to change the date in fullCalendar. All you need to do now is detect when someone has selected a date in the datepicker. have you checked the bootstrap datepicker documentation? It should explain that. https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html looks like it's probably the right link (if I have identified your plugin correctly)

Comment: @ADyson Sir I go through the document that you gave. It have the options for valid range with start and End Date,but my chosen year is get as variable and need to set  calendar under that year from Jan 1 to Dec 31.. Thats not available and I was completely stuck in this and confused..

Comment: fullCalendar does not have any "whole-year" view. You can choose from month, week, day, or (within the "agenda", "basic" or "list" views, a custom range specified in days. So if someone in your datepicker selects "2019" I would expect that you instruct fullCalendar to go to "2019-01-01", and then it will display that date according to whatever the current view type is (e.g. if current selected view type is month, then you will see January 19, if current view type is agendaWeek then you will see the week which contains Jan 1st, e.g. 2019-12-30 until 2019-01-05)

Comment: ....or if you specify some [custom view](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/custom-view-with-settings) then you'll see the specified time period of your view during which 1st Jan occurs (e.g. you could specify 14 days, 2, days, 365 days...)

Comment: P.S. you said the document I gave you "have the options for valid range with start and End Date"...but neither of the links I gave you mention this, as far as I can see. What are you looking at exactly?

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/validRange    --From this Page I saw the valid range option..

Comment: validRange is no good to you in this situation. That's for validating where a user can drag and drop events (or select to create new events). `visibleRange` might be useful though - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/visibleRange. This sets the exact date range which is visible in a view. Probably best to use it combined with a custom view, as I mentioned above - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/custom-view-with-settings. It's worth considering whether you really need to show a whole year at once though - that's a lot of data and it will be a lot to scroll through.

Comment: @ADyson Hi that visible range also not working for me. Actually, I choose and get my selected year as variable. but even I tried with normal date range of 3 months that mentioned in that given visible range like `visibleRange: {
                        start: '2017-03-22',
                        end: '2017-06-25'
                    }` but its not yet working for me.

Comment: Please show exactly how you tried it, with all your calendar config code, otherwise it's impossible to know what you might have done wrong. Here's a basic demo with visibleRange working: http://jsfiddle.net/fkq7hjyg/ . As you can see, a 3-month agenda is not a pretty sight. The list version isn't so bad. fullCalendar's max default view is one month long for a reason! Again, consider whether you really need a whole-year view...will the user want to see all of that at once??

Comment: @ADyson sorry mr.adyson, its my mistake who got confused myself with lot of tries.. your first answer `'gotoDate'` working for me now, it takes me to the year that I selected.sorry for troubled you.. Thank u so much. but only problem is, it displays next and prev yrs along with selected year. Lets say I chose 2010 mean, it goes to jan 2010 as starting year, but if I click prev mnth it goes to 2009 dec. I just want 2010 jan to dec only needs to display, if I click nxt btn after dec 2010 or If I click prev btn on jan2010, there must be no change is what I exactly what..

Comment: Ah ok well then that's what validRange is for :-)

Comment: Or...you could leave the buttons active, detect the change of view, and update the date picker to show the new year (if necessary). Gives your users more flexibility